# GitHub - pages Error: Docker pull failed with exit code 1

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my html,css,js website https://github.com/NevidX/Web to GitHub pages but I've got that error:

[image: image of error]

Comment: Hi @nevid, welcome to the community. Can you please follow the guidelines and put the error message in text form instead of link to image?

Comment: That just looks like a timeout. Have you tried re-running the job?

Comment: It's possible that `ghcr.io` was having trouble at that time. I ran `docker pull ghcr.io/actions/jekyll-build-pages:v1.0.3` on my local machine, and was able to verify that the `v1.0.3` tag is there and hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I resolve the problem just by creating new repository and trying to upload files one by one and I it worked. Also I tried to upload all files together then and it still worked. So problem wasn't from my side I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Settings, in the left column select Pages, then select `/(root)` file and save like this:

[image: like this]

Comment: Hi, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you